# Can I place multiple arrays on one chart using simple loop in c# instead of doing it one series at a time?

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach, charts

I have a code with a multitude of arrays, but let's say it's only five arrays in this example: aa, bb, cc, dd and ee which already have assigned values. I want to place these arrays on one chart (to compare values). I know I can do it one at a time, but I was wondering if there is some way to do it with a loop, where a floating array would pick up the values of the original arrays on each pass, and send its values onto a chart. Something like this:

```
        double[] aa = new double[100];
        double[] bb = new double[100];
        double[] cc = new double[100];
        double[] dd = new double[100];
        double[] ee = new double[100];

        double[] floatingArray = new double[100];

        // values to the first five arrays are assigned here...

        foreach (var series in chart1.Series)
        {
            /*
            a loop (or loops) where on each run floatingArray picks up values from
            the original five arrays in turns, and then sends them down to the
            following line of code:
            */
            series.Points.AddXY(someGenericValue.ToString(),floatingArray);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not invested in the 'floating array' idea, you could do it like this:

```
    var arrayData = new[]
    {
        new double[100],
        new double[100],
        new double[100],
        new double[100],
        new double[100]
    };

    // values to the first five arrays are assigned here...
    arrayData [0][0] = 1; // <- first element of the first array
    arrayData [0][1] = 2; // <- second element of the first array
    arrayData [1][0] = 1; // <- first element of the second array
    arrayData [3][51] = 2; // <- fifty-second element of the fourth array

    foreach (var series in chart1.Series)
    {
        foreach (var arrayItem in arrayData)
        {
            series.Points.AddXY(someGenericValue.ToString(), arrayItem);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting, looks very much like the thing I'd want, but how do I initialize values of different arrays through var arrayData? That's not something I've encountered before...

Comment: `arrayData` is an array of arrays, so you can populate it by accessing  each array in turn - I've updated my answer with some examples :)